# Angular "dynamic text"

Tags: angular, text, resources

I search the best way to make dynamic text in angular (latest version 4-5).

What i want to do exactly is to change easily all string resources of my web site, text can be change by someone that don't know how to code, so that should be in something that can get a front interface user (like xml editable file or database).
That should be change without re-deploy my web site (that should be dynamic at each moment) and like angular load all files in navigator we need to force reload the resource string that change from the latest visit (if i need to change version of my web site each time that we change resource string thats not really a problem for me but i don't know if thats possible and how to do this, like i never did it...).

I don't know if i18n can achieve this (i don't really need to internationalize text, like its a national web site). If that can tell me how please.

I don't know if i am pretty clear with this explanation (specially like english is not my mother language), so if you need more information for help me please tell me.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: You're looking for wordpress/drupal basically

Comment: Thanks Alexander, look like that can resolve my question, i will search in that way and test it.

Comment: Yes, i18n looks like the right tool. https://angular.io/guide/i18n#template-translations

Answer (score 0):

With Angular i18n you can change the locale of your application to any language.
You can extract the xlf file using ng xi18n command and load it to a translator to convert it to the required language, you should have added i18n attribute in the template though.
After this, you will build your application with the update xlf file.

Comment: Do you need to rebuild you app each time that you change a text in the XLF file? If that was the case that can't be satisfying for me like i need something that can be update by someone that don't know how to build an angular app and redeploy it.

Comment: In the production mode its not possible for a traditional approach as well where u switch the JSON files

Comment: So like i don't need to i18n (i just need one language for the moment) which solution would you preconize? Something in database and a webservice for text that should be updatable?